# Is there any way to load a custom google map into my website?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I already created a custom map and placed some markers but the embedded code doesn't work in my site, what i want is to load my custom map into my website and track the events when a user clicks on certain markers. Is there an "easy" way to do this or do i have to construct the map by code adding all the markers and stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a good tutorial on how to add markers to a google map: http://duncan99.wordpress.com/2011/09/25/google-maps-api-adding-markers/

Comment: This helped me a lot, thanks!. Let me edit my question again, i want to know if i can simply add my custom map that I've already created.

Answer (score 1):

Way to many questions.  You should probably take a look at [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/).  There are examples demonstrating everything you are trying to do.